# create new partition in place of deleted partition

Tags: partition, uefi

I am trying to create a EFI partition on the beginning of disk.
I had created one using what looked to be wrong type so I deleted it. (Wrong approach, I know, but here we are) Now I want to create a new partition in the same place on the SSD.

Using fdisk, I try to 'n' a partition but it will not let me specify `1` as the `First Sector` which is the sector to which I'd written the first attempt.

How can I insert a new partition into that spot?

Comment: First, understand that most partitioning tools have moved to a policy of aligning partitions on 1 MiB (2048-sector) boundaries as a way of improving performance with some types of arrays and some types of new hard disks (those with 4096-byte physical sectors). 
https://developer.ibm.com/technologies/linux/ & 
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-4kb-sector-disks/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot specify `1` as the first sector of a partition for a GPT partitioned disk.

See

- https://metebalci.com/blog/a-quick-tour-of-guid-partition-table-gpt/
- http://ntfs.com/guid-part-table.htm

for more information.

> The reason of first usable LBA being 34 is simple. LBA 0 is Protective MBR, LBA 1 is GPT Header and the required space for partition entries are:

```
128 partition * 128 bytes/partition / 512 bytes/block = 32 blocks
```

> 128 partition * 128 bytes/partition / 512 bytes/block = 32 blocks
> So 1 + 1 + 32 = 34 blocks are needed to store all GPT information, so first usable LBA can be minimum 34. As you might realize, these numbers change if the logical sector size (LBA block size) is not 512 bytes.

Use should use the lowest value allowed by fdisk.

Comment: ...and "you might rather want 2048 instead of that lowest value on either of SSD, SMR HDD or striped RAID for partition alignment issues".
Привет :-)